# Swift 4 macOS App - How to find the important users directories?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra, file-handling, macos-high-sierra

What is the easiest way with Swift 4 for a macOS application to find the important users directories like: Desktop, Documents, Downloads etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use FileManager urls method

```
func urls(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, in domainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask) -> [URL]
```

and pass `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory` `.desktopDirectory`, `.documentDirectory` or `.downloadsDirectory` for the user domain mask and get the first url returned:

```
let desktopDirectory  = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let downloadsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Comment: Why this returns me for .documentDirectory path file:///Users/username/Library/Containers/... and not path file:///Users/username/Documents/ ?

Comment: Dawy, I had this too. Most likely you need to give your app permission to access Downloads, Movies, etc. There are `Capabilities` tab and `File Access` area there. Check out the options there.

Comment: I'm struggling with this right now - it's a new problem, I've built successfully on Catalina before. Currently, my Capabilities "File Access" section doesn't mention anything about Documents, and I can't get the user's home directory Documents. Very frustrating.

Comment: Aha! got it. I'd accidentally somehow turned on Sandboxing in my app's Entitlements.

Comment: By default MacOS apps are sandboxed which means no access to Documents folder directly unless the user gives explicit access. So if you receive a documents URL of this lovely sort : `file:///Users/bioche/Library/Containers/com.bioche.UIApp/Data/Documents/pointFree/report.txt` check that in the entitlements file, the `App Sandbox` property is set to NO

Answer (score 12):

TLDR:

```
let desktopDir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let documentDir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let downloadsDir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

---

There are two methods to get this information, both from the `FileManager` class:

#### This one:

```
func urls(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, 
   in domainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask) -> [URL]
```

> Returns an array of URLs for the specified common directory in the requested domains. […] The directories are ordered according to the order of the domain mask constants, with items in the user domain first and items in the system domain last.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls

(already mentioned in @leo-dabus' answer)

#### And this one:

(which I prefer since it's more versatile and returns a single URL)

```
func url(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, 
  in domain: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask, 
  appropriateFor url: URL?, 
  create shouldCreate: Bool) throws -> URL
```

> Locates and optionally creates the specified common directory in a domain.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url

#### For either one:

The valid domains, defined in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager.searchpathdomainmask are:

> `.userDomainMask`: The user’s home directory—the place to install user’s personal items (~).
>
> `.localDomainMask`: Local to the
>   current machine—the place to install items available to everyone on
>   this machine.
>
> `.networkDomainMask`: Publicly available location in the
>   local area network—the place to install items available on the network
>   (/Network).
>
> `.systemDomainMask`: Provided by Apple—can’t be modified (/System) .
>
> `.allDomainsMask`: All domains.

There are lots of possibilities for the `directory` parameter, defined in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager.searchpathdirectory :

> `.applicationDirectory`: Supported applications (/Applications).
>
> `.demoApplicationDirectory`: Unsupported applications and demonstration
>   versions.
>
> `.developerApplicationDirectory`: Developer applications
>   (/Developer/Applications).
>
> `.adminApplicationDirectory` System and
>   network administration applications.
>
> `.libraryDirectory`: Various
>   user-visible documentation, support, and configuration files
>   (/Library).
>
> `.developerDirectory`: Developer resources (/Developer).
>
> `.userDirectory`: User home directories (/Users).
>
> `.documentationDirectory`: Documentation.
>
> `.documentDirectory`: Document directory.
>
> `.coreServiceDirectory`: Location of core services
>   (System/Library/CoreServices).
>
> `.autosavedInformationDirectory`:
>   Location of user’s autosaved documents (Library/Autosave Information).
>
> `.desktopDirectory`: Location of user’s desktop directory.
>
> `.cachesDirectory`: Location of discardable cache files (Library/Caches).
>
> `.applicationSupportDirectory`: Location of application support files
>   (Library/Application Support).
>
> `.downloadsDirectory`: Location of the
>   user’s downloads directory.
>
> `.inputMethodsDirectory`: Location of
>   Input Methods (Library/Input Methods).
>
> `.moviesDirectory`: Location of
>   user's Movies directory (~/Movies).
>
> `.musicDirectory`: Location of
>   user's Music directory (~/Music).
>
> `.picturesDirectory`: Location of
>   user's Pictures directory (~/Pictures).
>
> `.printerDescriptionDirectory`: Location of system's PPDs directory
>   (Library/Printers/PPDs).
>
> `.sharedPublicDirectory`: Location of user's
>   Public sharing directory (~/Public).
>
> `.preferencePanesDirectory`:
>   Location of the PreferencePanes directory for use with System
>   Preferences (Library/PreferencePanes).
>
> `.applicationScriptsDirectory`:
>   Location of the user scripts folder for the calling application
>   (~/Library/Application Scripts/),
>
> `.itemReplacementDirectory`: Passed to the  FileManager  method 
>   `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` in order to create a temporary
>   directory.
>
> `.allApplicationsDirectory`: All directories where
>   applications can occur.
>
> `.allLibrariesDirectory`: All directories
>   where resources can occur.
>
> `.trashDirectory`: Location of the trash
>   directory.